# Magento 2 - How to validate your input with custom validation

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

We have created custom attribute name "username" for customers.

We need to validate the username by allowing certain characters only.

i.e. Username should contain : `a-z A-Z 0-9 & .@_-` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Field :-**

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'username',
        'text',
        [   'name' => 'username', 
            'label' => __('Username'), 
            'title' => __('Username'),
            'validation' => ['validateUsername' => true]
        ]
    );
```

**Add a custom class validate-username to your field and then add below script to your form.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui', 
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
], function($){ 
    $.validator.addMethod(
        'validateUsername', function (value) { 
            return value.match(/^[+-]?\d+[.]?\d*[%]?$/g); //Add Matching Character or Special Symbol As per Your Requirement
         }, $.mage.__('Enter Valid Value')
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used data-validate attribute to define.